# Google cloud composer airflow - The triggerer does not appear to be running

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, airflow-2.x

GCP - Airflow instance is setup correctly and is working as expected, but after I enabled triggerer to run a deferrable operator, the UI presents with the below message

"The triggerer does not appear to be running.
Triggers will not run, and any deferred operator will remain deferred until it times out or fails."

Immediately I checked the logs to find out what is the reason and it seems, it is trying to find a class called

```
{
  "textPayload": "  class GCSXComBackend(BaseXCom):",
}
```

I further try to find where this class is available and it turns out it is available in "airflowHome/plugins/gs_xcom_backend.py"

I am pretty sure due to the limitations of xcom data sizes offered default, we setup a custom xcom backend (bucket) to store our xcom data

Please help!!

What I tried so far...

1. Disabled and Enabled triggerer.
2. Restarted the composer environment.

Nothing seems to be working :(